# A missing or empty content type header was found when trying to read a message. The content type header is required

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2012, odata

I am using a SAP odata service and I added it as a web reference in visual studio 2012.

```
 Uri serviceUri = new Uri("http://zbc.net:4521/sap/opu/odata/sap/Emp/", UriKind.Absolute);
            Emp context = new Emp(serviceUri);

            context.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("loginanme", "pass");

            var query = from b in context.Employees
                        where b.Role == "Admin"
                        select b;

            foreach (var myObject in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n name: {0} | role: {1}", myObject.name, myObject.Role);

            }
```

When I execute the code above, I get the following error:

```
"An error occurred while processing this request."

InnerException: "A missing or empty content type header was found when trying to read a message. The content type header is required."

this is the query that VS2012 produces:

Query: {http://zbc.net:4521/sap/opu/odata/sap/Emp/Employees()?$filter=Role eq 'Admin'}

StackTrace:

   at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataMessageReader.GetContentTypeHeader()
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataMessageReader.TryGetSinglePayloadKindResultFromContentType(IEnumerable`1& payloadKindResults, MediaType& contentType, Encoding& contentEncoding)
   at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataMessageReader.DetectPayloadKind()
   at System.Data.Services.Client.Materialization.ODataMaterializer.CreateODataMessageReader(IODataResponseMessage responseMessage, ResponseInfo responseInfo, Boolean projectionQuery, ODataPayloadKind& payloadKind)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.Materialization.ODataMaterializer.CreateMaterializerForMessage(IODataResponseMessage responseMessage, ResponseInfo responseInfo, Type materializerType, QueryComponents queryComponents, ProjectionPlan plan, ODataPayloadKind payloadKind)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.MaterializeAtom..ctor(ResponseInfo responseInfo, QueryComponents queryComponents, ProjectionPlan plan, IODataResponseMessage responseMessage, ODataPayloadKind payloadKind)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.CreateMaterializer(ProjectionPlan plan, ODataPayloadKind payloadKind)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.ProcessResult[TElement](ProjectionPlan plan)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
```

**Response from RESTClient (firefox add-on)**

```
Status Code: 200 OK
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 566
Content-Type: application/xml
Last-Modified: Tue, 09 Jul 2013 13:03:22 GMT
Server: SAP NetWeaver Application Server / ABAP 731
dataserviceversion: 2.0
```

**Response body**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <edmx:Edmx Version="1.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" 
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" 
    xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/Protocols/SAPData">
    <edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="2.0">
    <Schema Namespace="Emp" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm">
    <EntityType Name="Bank" sap:content-version="1">
    <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="Admin"/>
    </Key>
     <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="35" sap:label="Name"/>
    <Property Name="street" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="35" sap:label="Street"/>
    <Property Name="Role" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="35" sap:label="Role"/>
    <Property Name="Region" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="3" sap:label="Region"/>
    </EntityType>
    <EntityContainer Name="Emp" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
    <EntitySet Name="Employees" EntityType="Emp.Employee" sap:deletable="false" sap:content-version="1"/>
    </EntityContainer>
    <atom:link rel="self" href="http://zbc.net:4521/sap/opu/odata/sap/Emp/$metadata" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"/>
    <atom:link rel="latest-version" href="http://zbc.net:4521/sap/opu/odata/sap/Emp/$metadata" 
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"/>
    </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
    </edmx:Edmx>
```

**From Fiddler I get the following response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
www-authenticate: Basic realm="SAP NetWeaver Application Server [SVD/800]"
content-length: 2180
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
server: SAP NetWeaver Application Server / ABAP 731
```

How come in fiddler I get a 401? How can I provide a login and pass in Fiddler so that I don't get a 401?

Comment: Can you include the HTTP headers and payload of the response from the server that's causing this exception (using a tool like Fiddler)?

Comment: Can you try installing the latest WCF Data Services from NuGet?http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2013/05/30/wcf-data-services-5-5-0-release.aspx. The early releases of ODataLib where case sensitive on HTTP header names (which is technically correct, but some services don't work well with that).

Comment: I haven't added the WCF Data Services 5.5.0. yet. I have to download and install it in offline mode since we don't have access to internet in our dev machines

Comment: anyone has got any idea how to include the header in my calling code?

Comment: Are you sure those HTTP traces are coming from the right request?  The response xml you included is the kind of response you'd get from requesting $metadata, not `http://zbc.net:4521/sap/opu/odata/sap/Emp/Employees()`.  Also, did you get a chance to download the latest WCF Data Service client? I bet that will solve your problem.

Comment: (And it doesn't seem like this is a problem with the headers in the calling code, but rather the headers coming back from the server. I think SAP is returning a lowercase "content-type" header and the client doesn't recognize it.)

Comment: Hi Jen S, when I use http://zbc.net:4521/sap/opu/odata/sap/Emp/Employees() I get the data, but that is via the browser. 

the server administrator has installed Nuget Package Manager: Version 2.6.40627.9000. So I thing, WCF 5.5 should be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Vitek Karas MSFT for your suggestion. The issue is sovled by installing the latest version of WCF Data Services 5.6.0. and thanks to Maikel who tried in on our dev and was able to solve the issue.